# Problems getting Fragment in AndroidStudio 4.1.1 wizard to compile "error: incompatible types: Class cannot be converted to Fragment"

Tags: android, android-fragments

There are similar questions with the confusion over android.app.Fragment vs v4's Fragment that date back to 2014. I'm using AndroidX and Android Studio 4.1.1 so I don't want to use the v4 support.

The wizard creates a Fragment class from `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` that looks like this:

```
package foo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link ActivationFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ActivationFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public ActivationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment ActivationFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ActivationFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ActivationFragment fragment = new ActivationFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activation, container, false);
    }
}
```

In my activity I have a layout for the fragment:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And in the activity I am trying to put the fragment in the view:

```
 FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
 manager.beginTransaction()
 .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, ActivationFragment.class, null)
 .commit();
```

And in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.2.5"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
}
```

Error from compile:

```
error: incompatible types: Class<ActivationFragment> cannot be converted to Fragment
                .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, com.foo.ActivationFragment.class, null)
```

I'm not sure if the problem is confusion over androidX or something else.

I also read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments) which looks like Google updated just 2 months ago. I have based my Activity on both `AppCompatActivity` and `FragmentActivity` with no difference in compile error.

Comment: You provided the code for WelcomeFragment, but the fragment referenced in your Activity and that is referenced in the error is ActivationFragment. Could you check which version of Fragment ActivationFragment is using?

Comment: Sorry, ActivationFragment and WelcomeFragment were identical. Both were dummys created using the wizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `getFragmentManager()`, which uses the framework `android.app.Fragment` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`, which uses AndroidX Fragments as per the [Adding a fragment programmatically documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic).

Comment: Note that that same page also details how to [add the fragment via XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-xml) just by adding the `android:name` attribute to your `FragmentContainerView`, skipping the need to write any code to add your initial fragment.

Comment: It does, but I can't do that. There's some startup processing where I need to determine whether to have a generic Welcome fragment or an Activation fragment dynamically. Thanks for the answer, that worked. Honestly wish AndroidX had renamed classes like Fragment to clear up confusion over which Fragment is specified.

Comment: If you're using any modern `compileSdkVersion`, `getFragmentManager()` should appear as deprecated, giving you a very clear sign that you shouldn't be using it.